# cvs commit "The chosen operation is not enabled" error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, commit, cvs

I'm trying to commit my changes into the CVS using eclipse. But when I right click on the folder I want to check in and select Team->Commit. I get an error saying "the chosen operation is not enabled." The '>' indicator(file changed indicator) in my project explorer also disappears and the 'CVS' folder(which was created on checkout) also gets deleted. Now I cant even find out the files I have changed after checking out. Also I cannot commit these files to the repository now. The Team->Commit option is now disabled.
Any idea why this could be happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the exact same issue, and found the root cause in my case:
The content of the file MyProject/CVS/Entries was erroneous. Normally this file should contain lines starting with "D" for each sub-directory of the project, like this:

```
/.clean-missing-file.done/1.1/Thu Nov 21 08:15:43 2013//
/.cvsignore/1.1/Thu Dec 16 22:41:49 2010//
/.package.xml/1.28/Fri Dec 27 16:09:52 2013//
D/Input_API////
D/Sources////
```

But in my case, the sub-directories were not referenced in this file, causing Eclipse to believe that they were not CVS-managed. As soon as I tried to perform a CVS operation on a file in the folder tree, all the CVS sub-directories got removed.

Maybe you should check the content of your root CVS/Entries file?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I can solution this:

Menu: Help > About eclipse > Installation details
After you have to select "Eclipse CVS Client" and press the "update" button.

Sorry for my English